# Adding online map to QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

Looking for info on how to add the web mapping services from the Greek Archaeological Cadastre website to QGIS.

There appears to be no way since there is no WFS/WMS link to add but do you have any other help/ideas?

The link to the site is this https://www.arxaiologikoktimatologio.gov.gr/en

Comment: did you check this plugin: https://github.com/lymperis-e/Greek-Data-QGIS-Plugin